# Can TortoiseGit work with Windows 7's "make available offline"?

Tags: windows-7, indexing, windows-7-x64, tortoisegit, offline-caching

Under Windows 7 SP1 (64 bit), I have been using a `git` repository stored on SMB share made available by a Linux machine. I've made it available offline (right-click in Win7 Explorer, select "Always available offline") and I dimly remember the directory is being indexed by Win7.

I've made some commits, resets, branches and the like with TortoiseGit and I never got any warnings or error messages. When looking at the shared directory from my local machine, everything looks fine, but when I look at the file share from another machine, I see that the MS Word 2010 file (.docm) I've been working on is gone (!) and there are lots of .tmp files in the directory, all corresponding to different versions of that Word file:

[image]

While I managed to work out that the last .tmp file is what I was looking for, this is not really nice to work with...

Has anyone seen such a problem? Can TortoiseGit be made to work with Windows 7's "work available offline" functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's incompatible with offline dirs, seeing what you noticed. But given the fact that git is distributed, I don't see any interest in working in this manner, since cloning the repository from the SMB share to your local machine does what you want, with much more features and controls that Git gives to you